# Prove the set of all dyadic numbers is countable

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

A number is said to be dyadic if it has the form $\frac{k}{2^n}$ for some integers $k$
and $n$ in $\mathbb Z^+ $. Show that the set of all dyadic numbers is countable.

Here is a proof I have (but couldn't complete),

Proof:
Let $ M_k := \{ \frac{k}{2^n}: n \in \mathbb Z^+ \}$ for each $k \in \mathbb Z^+$

To show that $M_k$ is countable for any $k$, I tried to construct a one-to-one mapping from $M_k \to \mathbb N$. But I couldn't be sure if such a mapping is correct: $\frac{k}{2^m} \mapsto m-1$ (or while mapping is the left hand side always a single variable such as x so I have to do mapping like $x \mapsto ...$?). After mapping, I will show that the function(mapping) is one-to-one. Since $M_k$ is countable and the countable union of countable sets is countable, the set of dyadic numbers is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is just fine.

Notice, however, that $0 \not \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$ and thus you do not need to have $\frac{k}{2^m}\mapsto m-1$.

Also, it is totally fine to write the mapping like you did, with

$$\frac{k}{2^m} \mapsto m$$

If it confuses you, you can also instead define a one-to-one correspondence from $\mathbb{N} \to M_k$ by

$$m \mapsto \frac{k}{2^m}$$

Comment: But then $\mathbb N \to M_k $ wouldn't prove that $M_k$ is countable, I need to show the function is onto I believe.

Comment: not necessarily, you need to find one-to-one correspondence in that case since the function could be one-to-one but the cardinality of $M_k$ could be larger than $\mathbb N$. Also you can find a mapping $\mathbb N \to \mathbb R $ that is one-to-one but their cardinality is not the same

Comment: @Pumpkin I may have misled you! I read "one-to-one" as "bijection" because of my native language. Sorry for that! "One-to-one" means injective, doesn't it?

Comment: Clarifying,
If you find a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to M_k$ you show that $\mathbb{N}$ and $M_k$ have the same cardinality, hence showing that $M_k$ is countable.

Comment: @RGS: "'One-to-one' means injective, doesn't it?": Correct. (But, oddly enough, "one-to-one correspondence" means "bijective function".)

Answer (score 6):

The set $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+$ is countable and, by definition,$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+&\longrightarrow&\{\text{dyadic numbers}\}\\(k,n)&\mapsto&\dfrac k{2^n}\end{array}$$is surjective. Therefore, the set of dyadic numbers is either finite or countable. But since it is infinite, it is countable.

Comment: What you said is fine but your answer feels somewhat "inappropriate" when compared to what the OP wrote and asked...

Comment: @RGS Yes, I should have read more carefully what the OP wrote.